# Selenium webdriver Java code using web driver for double click a record in a grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to write selenium java code for `doubleClick()` on a record using web driver?

I have displayed some records in the body part. Once I clicked on a record we should get a popup window to update it.

Please suggest how to write Selenium Java code using web driver.

I have tried following code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[1]"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Comment: please provide your code for better understanding of the problem

Comment: @AAB I have posted the code which I have tried

Comment: ah, please give us html snippet so we can see how your elements look in the page

Comment: @paul.cioroianu I have posted the code to the question which i have tried to double click a row on the grid. With this code only the row in the grid is selected but not double clicked. If I double click the row then i will be getting a pop up displayed. Could you please help me?

Comment: @Gokul you could just try to call click on it twice. the method findElement will return the element for you, so just call element.click() and see if that works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[1]"))).doubleClick().perform();
```

This code works!!!

Answer (score 21):

Use [Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class to perform mouse, keyboard actions on WebElements using WebDriver.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("TEST"));

//Double click
action.doubleClick(element).perform();

//Mouse over
action.moveToElement(element).perform();

//Right Click
action.contextClick(element).perform();
```

Comment: I tried with your code to implement this using xpath but it did not worked.  I have posted the code to the question which i have tried to double click a row on the grid. With this code only the row in the grid is selected but not double clicked. If I double click the row in the grid then a pop up should be displayed. Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you please share your html code here to help you further?

Is that link is in iframe ?

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `Actions()` class as this includes a 'double-click' action.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement btnElement=driver.findElement("Locator of element"));
action.doubleClick(btnElement).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **Actions** class of WebDriver to perform composite actions like
***Double click, Drag and Drop, Hover*** etc.

***// Creates an instance of Actions class, passing current driver instance.***

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
```

**Way 1:**

***// Gets an Action class object that holds an action/ a set of actions***

```
Action action = builder.doubleClick(element);
```

***// Builds the set of actions/ single action using build() and executes on    browser using perform() method.***

```
action.build().perform();
```

**Way 2:**

***// Calls build() and perform() methods directly on Actions class instance***

```
builder.doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case if have no additional actions binded to singleclick, you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("%youXPath%"))).click;
driver.findElement(By.xpath("%youXPath%"))).click;
```

Actually, it should works in most cases (except you have some custom system doubleclick settings)

Answer (score 0):

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(selector);
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
  builder.doubleClick(element).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Ran's (immediately above my post) solution. I'm writing Java in Eclipse and using Selenium WebDriver.

There are 2 imports that you'll need:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Then, I implemented the code thusly:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.doubleClick(element).perform();
```

Thanks to Ran!
I'd been struggling with this one for several hours. Invoking the single click twice doesn't work for me - too much time between the events to be captured by the browser under test as a double-click.