# DoubleClick speed in selenium

Tags: selenium

We have problem that doubleClick in selenium isn't working.

We are using [Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) for perform doubleClick like appear here: [Selenium webdriver Java code using web driver for double click a record in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907007/selenium-webdriver-java-code-using-web-driver-for-double-click-a-record-in-a-gri).

After investigation and several attempts we found that it is related to the **speed of the doubleClick**. As you may know, [speed of doubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760404(v=vs.85).aspx) can be change. Is there any option to set the speed of doubleClick in selenium?

Code used to perform the double click:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.doubleClick(element).build().perform();
```

And we try without 'build' too:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.doubleClick(element).perform();
```

Comment: can you please share your code you did?

Comment: how do you actually make sure it's about speed?

Comment: In the application, we are using yfiles and we have the option to play with doubleClick speed: 'yfiles.input.SystemInformation.doubleClickTimeSpan'. So we change the speed and the doubleClick work.

Answer (score 0):

As seems you are using customized timing for double-click in your application, i suggest to try use 2 separated clicks with wait same between them of same customized timing. i think it's easiest way to control timing between two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative workaround described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004164/perform-doubleclick-on-element-that-have-that/35004330)

Simplified answer (change to needed element):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('map_container').dispatchEvent(new Event('dblclick'));");
```