# How do I edit a text field using double-click?

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver

I want to use double-click to edit (update, not totally remove) manually added text using Selenium & Selenide using the Page object model.

```
public void EditSmth(String name){
    tasks.find(text(name)).hover().doubleClick().setValue("cow");
}
```

CSS before double-clicking the text field looks like

```
<section id="main" data-woven="troopjs-todos/widget/display@6" style="display: block;">
   <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox" data-woven="troopjs-todos/widget/mark@8" />
   <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
   <ul id="todo-list" data-woven="troopjs-todos/widget/list@12">
      <li class="active" data-index="0">
         <div class="view">
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
            <label>sdsd</label>
            <button class="destroy" />
         </div>
         <input class="edit" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

after double-click

```
<section id="main" data-woven="troopjs-todos/widget/display@6" style="display: block;">
   <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox" data-woven="troopjs-todos/widget/mark@8" />
   <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
   <ul id="todo-list" data-woven="troopjs-todos/widget/list@12">
      <li class="active editing" data-index="0">
         <div class="view">
            <input class="edit" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: could you use clear() to change the value?

Comment: no. I need to update old text without clearing. the cause problem that Ican not open active editing via doubleclick

Comment: does this solution work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907007/selenium-webdriver-java-code-using-web-driver-for-double-click-a-record-in-a-gri

Comment: no. The problem's that the class's changed from "Active" to "active editing" and I link DoubleClick a bit wrong