# Have to double click the buttons on a webpage while using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using this code to click on on a button

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();
```

I tried using:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Sign up")))
```

but it did not work.

Comment: send me the URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver Java code using web driver for double click a record in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907007/selenium-webdriver-java-code-using-web-driver-for-double-click-a-record-in-a-gri)

Comment: Where is your code that attempts the double click? You only have a wait for an element to be clickable but never click it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample as you does not mention URL:

```
WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();     
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2014/09/selectable.html");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Double-Click Me To See Alert')]"));

//To generate double click action on "Double-Click Me To See Alert" button.
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(ele);
action.perform();
```

**Go through this URL to learn more:**

[http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/01/double-click-on-button-using-actions.html](http://Double%20Click%20functionality%20reference)